# How to get a static value on a select query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to get static value as result in codeigniter?

it works in simple PHP query
`$this->db->query("select 'mytype' as type from users where id='1'")->result();`
output: type = 'mytype'

but when i try with codeigniter it gives error saying unknown column.

```
$this->db->select("'mytype' as type");
$this->db->where('id','1');
$this->db->get('users')->result();
```

it gives error: no mytype column.

Please help for this in codeigniter to get static value in output result.

Comment: This is not valid SQL. `AS` is alias setting keyword for a table. i.e you should: `SELECT type.mytype from users AS type WHERE id='1'`

Comment: sir, 'mytype' is not my column name. i need this predefined value in my output result for next steps. and i need this using the CodeIgniter's steps.

Comment: Hi, i have got the solutions to the above problem to get static value in result using codeigniter.

    $this->db->select("'mytype' as type");
    $this->db->where('id','1');
    $this->db->get('users')->result();

need to change to:

    $this->db->select("\'mytype\' as type");
    $this->db->where('id','1');
    $this->db->get('users')->result();

This will output your defined value in type column. \'....\' is the key we need to use for our static values.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, with ActiveRecord in Rails. Frustrating that most of the replies missed the fact that the OP wants the *static string value* of 'mytype' as data...that it is not a field name.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;`  before running your codeigniter query. To handle those kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use single quotes at field name. Use ` character instead.

```
"select `mytype` as type from users where id='1'"
```

If you run thin in sql: `SELECT 'abcdefgh' as item;`

you will get back this:

```
item
--------------
abcdefgh
```

Comment: i know this in php and worked to get output as my defined value. but i want this in CodeIgniter to get the static or my defined  value as output

Answer (score 0):

Your codeigniter query should be :

```
$this->db->select("mytype as type");
$this->db->where('id','1');
$this->db->get('users')->result();
```

Remove single quote from `mytype`.

And Remove also extra `s` form result().

Comment: hi, actually 'mytype' is not any column in my table. i need this or some my pre defined value as type in output result. i need this extra output to validate my result in further steps. it worked in simple php query, but face difficulty with Codeigniter query.

Comment: i think this statement is not working in codeigniter query.  i also face this issue now.